# Spring tells that it fails to create bean because a parameter bean is missing, but there is no such parameter in @Bean method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to run a SpringBoot application and see an error:

```
Parameter 1 of method methodName in com.example.app.config.ConfigClassName required a bean named 'beanName1' that could not be found.
```

This is how this bean declaration looks like

```
    @Bean
    CustomRedisSubscriber methodName(BeanName2 beanName2, BeanName3 beanName3,
                                    BeanName4 beanName4)
    {
        return new CustomRedisSubscriber(beanName2, beanName3, beanName4);
    }
```

I mean this @Bean method doesn't have any parameter that looks like "beanName1".
Class BeanName1 and @Bean method that creates bean of BeanName1 class were deleted from source code.

I rebased to the previous version where class BeanName1 existed and bean with name "beanName1" was declared and checked  `@Bean CustomRedisSubscriber methodName` in debug mode - there was no parameter with the name "beanName1" available in the method methodName.

The funniest thing is that when I created a bean declaration with type String and named "beanName1" the error disappeared.

```
    @Bean
    String beanName1() {
        return "This is beanName1String";
    }
```

Any ideas why it may happen?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rebuild the project as spring seems to still use the old sources

Comment: I checked *.class files and rebuilt the project. I don't think that it is the reason. There is no such parameter  In old sources as well.

Comment: Debug the wiring of your Spring Application with your IDE, this should reveal your code that demands `beanName1`. Or just search for `beanName1` in your code base.

Comment: @Andreas, thank you so much! :) "Find in files" helped to find a class where one of the parameters was created with @DependsOn(value = "beanName1"). This is why I didn't find it when I tried to debug it with a breakpoint in a constructor of this parameter class.